# FPDF - MemImage problems - OO syntax

Tags: php, fpdf

```
require('inc/fpdf.php');
require('inc/mem_image.php');



class PDF extends FPDF
{
    // Colored table
    function FancyTable()
    {
        $this->SetFont('Helvetica','B');
        $this->Cell(27, 4, 'Other Title', 1, 0);
    }  
}


$pdf = new PDF_MemImage();
//$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',7);
$pdf->AddPage();

$img = file_get_contents('logo.jpg');

$pdf->MemImage($img, 50, 30);
$pdf->Cell(20,10,'Title',1,1,'C');

//$pdf->FancyTable();
$pdf->Output();
```

I am trying to incorporate the mem_image script into my existing FPDF pages. I am using a method called fancyTable to set up my table data/layout. Unfortunately trying to call fancyTable breaks the page (blank). If I comment it out, its fine. If I switch out the $pdf declaration to new PDF() instead of new PDF_memimage() fancyTable works, but obviously my image doesn't load. I think its probably just a conflict with the class, but I am not versed in OO syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is actually quite straight forward: you have extended the wrong class.

All you need to do to fix it is change this:

```
class PDF extends FPDF
```

...to this:

```
class PDF extends PDF_MemImage
```

...and then change this:

```
$pdf = new PDF_MemImage();
```

...to this:

```
$pdf = new PDF();
```

By extending `FPDF`, you have created a new branch in the inheritance tree based on the *trunk* (`FPDF`), whereas what you want to do is base it on the existing branch `PDF_MemImage`.

For the record, naming your class `PDF` is probably not a great idea - firstly it's not very descriptive (it doesn't indicate that it inherits from FPDF or MemImage) and secondly it is very short and would run the risk of collision with another class if used as part of a larger application. I personally would call it `FPDF_MemImage_FancyTable`, YMMV.

Also, in this day and age, there really is no need to write classes that are PHP4 compatible. (In saying this, I actually *do* need to do this occasionally, but I doubt you do)

**EDIT**

In case it's not clear from the above description, the final code would look like this:

```
require('inc/fpdf.php');
require('inc/mem_image.php');

class FPDF_MemImage_FancyTable extends PDF_MemImage
{
    // Colored table
    function FancyTable()
    {
        $this->SetFont('Helvetica','B');
        $this->Cell(27, 4, 'Other Title', 1, 0);
    }  
}

$pdf = new FPDF_MemImage_FancyTable();

$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',7);
$pdf->AddPage();

$img = file_get_contents('logo.jpg');
$pdf->MemImage($img, 50, 30);

$pdf->Cell(20,10,'Title',1,1,'C');

$pdf->FancyTable();

$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: Yep that did it. I knew it was either the Class name or the extends that I was getting wrong. Thanks for your help.